# Display Firestore Data with a datatype of map: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Retrieving from firestore:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

  const getProducts = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "products"));
    const arr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      arr.push({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      });
    });
    setProduct(arr);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);
```

I have this `colorMap` retrieved from Firestore:

```
export const data = [
  {
    colorMap: { red: 6, blue: 7, green: 8 },
    id: "a4TK38mByQbim4TwOHMY"
  },
  
  {
    colorMap: { Black: 20, Gold: 10 },
    id: "m08YmrlFxhxLxyc3hVjT"
  },
  {
    colorMap: { green: 9, red: 19 },
    id: "nN2w57SiDovbtQ6EBzGb"
  }
];
```

How can I display it in the screen?

```
 {product &&
        product.map((index) => (
          <>
            <b>{index.prodName + "-" + index.size + index.cat}</b>
            <li>{index.id}</li>
          </>
        ))}
```

If I'll add this:

```
<li>{index.colorMap}</li>
```

It will cause an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child
> (found: object with keys {green, red, blue})

How do I resolve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then map those items as shown below:

```
{product &&
  product.map((index) => (
  <div>
    <b>{index.prodName + "-" + index.size + index.cat}</b>
    <p>{index.id}</p>
    <ul>
      {
        Object.entries(index.colorMap).map((color) => (
          <li>{color[0]} - {color[1]}</li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
))}
```